# Finding highest total score and displaying student information that has it

Tags: c, arrays, max, structure, min

I'm having a problem here figuring out the top total score for number (n) of students and displaying information for the student how got it.
please don't mind unuseful information, I'm sorry the code is too long long, but I would appreciate a help.
thank you!!

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
//Function Prototype
void add( struct student s[] );
void deleting( struct student s[] );
void update( struct student s[] );
void view( struct student s[] );
void calculateAvg( struct student s[] );
void max( struct student s[] );
/*void min( struct student s[] );
void find( struct student s[] );
void sort( struct student s[] );*/
//Size
int size = 0;
//Structure
struct student{
int id;
char name[25];
char sex; // M(Male) || F(Female)
int q1,q2,mid,final,total;

 }s[20];

int main()
{

int choice;

system("CLS");

printf("\n==========================");
printf("\n         MENU");
printf("\n==========================");

printf("\n1. Add student records");
printf("\n2. Delete student records");
printf("\n3. Update student records");
printf("\n4. View all student records");
printf("\n5. Calculate an average of a selected student’s scores");
printf("\n6. Show student who gets the max total score");
printf("\n7. Show student who gets the min total score");
printf("\n8. Find student by ID");
printf("\n9. Sort records by total scores");
printf("\n10. EXIT!");

printf("\n\n Please enter your choice:  ");
scanf("%d",&choice);

switch(choice)
{
    case 1: add(s);break;
    case 2: deleting(s);break;
    case 3: update(s);break;
    case 4: view(s);break;
    case 5: calculateAvg(s);break;
    case 6: max(s);break;
    /*case 7: min(s);break;
    case 8: find(s);break;
    case 9: sort(s);break;
    case 10: exit(1);break;*/
}

getch();

}

void add( struct student s[] )
{
char choice;
int j;

system("CLS");

printf("\nPlease enter student no.%d information below:\n",size+1);
printf("ID : ");
scanf("%d",&s[size].id);
printf("Name : ");
scanf("%s",&s[size].name);
printf("Sex [M=Male||F=Female] : ");
scanf(" %c",&s[size].sex);
printf("Quiz1: ");
scanf("%d",&s[size].q1);
printf("Quiz2: ");
scanf("%d",&s[size].q2);
printf("Mid-term: ");
scanf("%d",&s[size].mid);
printf("Final: ");
scanf("%d",&s[size].final);

++size;

printf("ADD PROCESS COMPLETE!");
printf("    SIZE=%d",size);
printf("\nPRESS (R) TO RETURN, PRESS (A) TO ADD: ");
scanf(" %c",&choice);

if ( choice == 'R' || choice == 'r')
main();
else if ( choice == 'a' || choice == 'A')
add(s);

getch();

}


void deleting( struct student s[] )
{
int num,i,j,flag=0;
char choice;

system("CLS");

printf("Please enter student ID to delete: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

for ( i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    if ( s[i].id == num )
    {
        for (j=i; j<size; ++j)
        {
            s[j] = s[j+1];

        }
        --size;
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
}



if (flag==1)
printf("DELETE PROCESS IS DONE!");
else if (flag==0)
printf("ERROR!!");

printf("\nPRESS (R) TO RETURN, PRESS (D) TO DELETE: ");
scanf(" %c",&choice);

if ( choice == 'R' || choice == 'r')
main();
else if ( choice == 'D' || choice == 'd')
deleting(s);



getch();
}


void update( struct student s[] )
{
int i,num,flag=0;
char choice;

system("CLS");

printf("Please enter student ID to update: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

for ( i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    if ( s[i].id == num )
    {
        flag=1;
        printf("\nStudent no.%d information:\n",i+1);
        printf("ID:%d |",s[i].id);
        printf("Name:%s |",s[i].name);
        printf("Sex:%c |",s[i].sex);
        printf("Quiz1:%d |Quiz2:%d |Mid-term:%d |Final:%d |",s[i].q1,s[i].q2,s[i].mid,s[i].final);

        printf("\n\nPlease enter new inforamtion to update: \n\n");

            printf("ID : ");
            scanf("%d",&s[i].id);
            printf("Name : ");
            scanf("%s",&s[i].name);
            printf("Sex [M=Male||F=Female] : ");
            scanf(" %c",&s[i].sex);
            printf("Quiz1: ");
            scanf("%d",&s[i].q1);
            printf("Quiz2: ");
            scanf("%d",&s[i].q2);
            printf("Mid-term: ");
            scanf("%d",&s[i].mid);
            printf("Final: ");
            scanf("%d",&s[i].final);

            break;

    }

}


if (flag==1)
    printf("UPDATE PROCESS IS DONE!");
else if (flag==0)
    printf("ERROR!!");

printf("\nPRESS (R) TO RETURN, PRESS (U) TO UPDATE: ");
scanf(" %c",&choice);

if ( choice == 'R' || choice == 'r')
main();
else if ( choice == 'U' || choice == 'u')
update(s);

getch();
}


void view( struct student s[] )
{
char choice;
//system("CLS"); may be added if wanted.
for (int j=0; j<size; ++j)
{
    printf("\nStudent no.%d information:\n",j+1);
    printf("ID:%d |",s[j].id);
    printf("Name:%s |",s[j].name);
    printf("Sex:%c |",s[j].sex);
    printf("Quiz1:%d |Quiz2:%d |Mid-term:%d |Final:%d |",s[j].q1,s[j].q2,s[j].mid,s[j].final);

}

printf("\n\nSIZE=%d",size);

printf("\nPRESS (R) TO RETURN :");
scanf(" %c",&choice);

if ( choice == 'R' || choice == 'r')
main();    

getch();

 }


 void calculateAvg( struct student s[] )
{
int i,total,flag=0,num;
char choice;

    system("CLS");

printf("Please enter student ID to calculate average of marks: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

for ( i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    if ( s[i].id == num )
    {
        s[i].total = s[i].q1 + s[i].q2 + s[i].mid + s[i].final;

        printf("\n\n            Student no.%d information:\n",i+1);
        printf("ID:%d |",s[i].id);
        printf("Name:%s |",s[i].name);
        printf("Sex:%c |",s[i].sex);
        printf("Quiz1:%d |Quiz2:%d |Mid-term:%d |Final:%d |",s[i].q1,s[i].q2,s[i].mid,s[i].final);

        printf("\n\n        TOTAL = %d",s[i].total);
        printf("\n      AVERAGE = %d",s[i].total/4);

        flag=1;
    }
    break;
}

 if (flag==1)
    printf("\n\nAVERAGE CALCULATED!");
else if (flag==0)
    printf("ERROR!!");

printf("\nPRESS (R) TO RETURN :");
scanf(" %c",&choice);

if ( choice == 'R' || choice == 'r')
main();


getch();

}


void max( struct student s[] )
{
int i,max;
s[i].total = s[i].q1 + s[i].q2 +s[i].mid + s[i].final 
max = s[0].total;

for (i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    if ( s[i].total > max )
    {
            max = s[i].total;
    }
}

printf("\nHighest total score is %d belongs to student ID (%d)",max,)//\\problem
 }
```

Comment: *Use a **debugger***. And right now the problem is `max()` won't compile because of syntax errors, including a missing semi-colon on the second line, and failing to complete the argument list for the final `printf` call. If you're going to post a wall of code, (a) don't, and (b) when you ignore (a), at least make sure it compiles.

Comment: Sir, if you remove max() it does compile and my problem is just max(), I didn't want to crop the program so it makes sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am unsure of what you are trying to do with this line: `s[i].total = s[i].q1 + s[i].q2 + s[i].mid + s[i].final`. But I modified your method slightly.

```
void max( struct student s[] )
{
    int i, max, id;
    s[0].total = s[0].q1 + s[0].q2 + s[0].mid + s[0].final 
    max = s[0].total;
    id = s[0].id;

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        s[i].total = s[i].q1 + s[i].q2 + s[i].mid + s[i].final
        if ( s[i].total > max )
        {
                max = s[i].total;
                id = s[i].id;
        }
    }

    printf("\nHighest total score is %d belongs to student ID (%d)", max, id)//\\problem
}
```

So in this solution I added an id, which is assigned based on your student Id. When a new max is found that id is updated. Max is initialized with the first students total. You can try working with something like this?

Comment: But total is not defined as the sum of marks, I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: I modified the loop slightly. I added the line to sum up q1, q2, q3 and final. Is this the total score for that student? If so that should do the trick for you. Or something very similar.

Comment: That worked thank you very much!, I've just got the concept :)